# Maven - Non-resolvable parent POM, Could not find artifact SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build a maven project. I don't have experience in building Java projects, and this is my first maven project. I have tried to build the project from both the terminal and the IntelliJ, and I am receiving this error when I run `mvn clean install`:

```
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for my.project.tk.at.batcher:batcher:${revision}: 
Could not find artifact my.project.tk.at:parentpom:pom:5.20.0-SNAPSHOT and
'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

This is the `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>my.project.tk.at</groupId>
        <artifactId>parentpom</artifactId>
        <version>5.20.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>my.project.tk.at.batcher</groupId>
    <artifactId>batcher</artifactId>
    <name>batcher</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>${revision}</version>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@git.my.project.no/autfor/jobscheduler.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@git.my.project.no/autfor/jobscheduler.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://git.my.project.no/projects/AUTFOR/repos/jobscheduler</url>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <maven.javadoc.failOnError>false</maven.javadoc.failOnError>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <version.patch>0</version.patch>
        <revision>${version.major}.${version.minor}.${version.patch}-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    </properties>

    <!-- Shared build properties -->
    <modules>
        <module>batcher-common</module>
        <module>batcher-sql</module>
        <module>scheduler</module>
        <module>notifier-batch</module>
        <module>notifier-examtime-batch</module>
        <module>notifier-attest-batch</module>
        <module>ssb-batch</module>
        <module>alert-user-batch</module>
        <module>delete-history-batch</module>
        <module>alert-user-about-delivery-batch</module>
        <module>batcher-main</module>
        <module>delete-quarantine-batch</module>
    </modules>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>svv-artrepo-release</id>
            <name>svv-artrepo-release</name>
            <url>https://artrepo.remote-project.no/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>svv-artrepo-snapshots</id>
            <name>svv-artrepo-snapshots</name>
            <url>https://artrepo.remote-project.no/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <!--        <repository>-->
        <!--            <id>nexus-release-repository</id>-->
        <!--            <name>Nexus release repo</name>-->
        <!--            <url>http://10.250.4.100:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>-->
        <!--        </repository>-->
        <!--        <snapshotRepository>-->
        <!--            <id>nexus-snapshot-repository</id>-->
        <!--            <url>http://10.250.4.100:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>-->
        <!--            <layout>default</layout>-->
        <!--        </snapshotRepository>-->
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- copy from common master, since ${project.build.directory} gets false value if it is not duplicated -->
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                                <append>true</append>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-report</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Exclude all generated sources -->
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/wsgen/**/*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>codecoverage</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>owasp</id>
            <reporting>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-project-info-reports-plugin.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.owasp.dependency-check-maven.version}</version>
                        <reportSets>
                            <reportSet>
                                <reports>
                                    <report>aggregate</report>
                                </reports>
                            </reportSet>
                        </reportSets>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </reporting>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you show your pom file so we can see how it is configured?

Comment: I have added the pom file to the question

Comment: Your `<parent>` section points to a `pom.xml` artifact. Where do expect it to be found? Is it available in your remote repo? Or maybe it's available as a local file? Anyway, Maven can't find it. It should either be located 1 folder-level above, or in your local Maven repo, or in remote Maven repo (Nexus, Artifactory).

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev  It is not locally, I believe it is in the remote Maven repo

Comment: Try add `<relativePath></relativePath>` in your `<parent></parent>` tag.

Comment: @Leff, if it's in a remote repo then try to find it there. If it's there, then ensure that that repo is included either in `<repositories>` section in your pom.xml or in settings.xml in `<mirrors>` or `<repositories>`.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the parent POM `my.project.tk.at:parentpom:pom:5.20.0-SNAPSHOT` cannot be found.

So it is not in your local repository (you haven't built it locally and you haven't used it before) and it is also not in any of the remote repositories you specified (if you specified any in your `settings.xml` or `pom.xml`).

So either correct the parent POM to the one you are really looking for or see why the desired parent POM is not in the specified repositories. Also read the helpful comments of Stanislav Bashkyrtsev.